# Does WCF service method have something equivalent to ASP.NET Application_EndRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, idisposable

I want to `Dispose` of some objects that are created during a WCF service method, but I need to clean them up outside of the scope of the method that created them. When I'm working in ASP.NET, I normally call that code during the `Application_EndRequest` event.

If the answer is: there is no `Application_EndRequest`-like event in WCF, how should I go about cleaning up my objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement **IDisposable**  for your WCF service. If the service is configured **PerSession** or **PerCall** **context mode** dispose method will be called once the channel is closed and the service instance is dropped.

Comment: Thanks. As a side note, I was able to follow [this guide](http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/17/abstracting-request-state/) to manage state for my WCF request ... which was my ultimate goal.